# Ho to call own toast message from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I definied my own method to display Toast and I want to call it from another Activity. When I do that, my app crash. Do you have some `Attempt to invoke virtual method.... on a null object reference`.

The Toast method:

```
 public void showToastDown(Context context, String message) {
    context = getApplicationContext();

    inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_down, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_down_root));

    TextView tvToastDown = v.findViewById(R.id.tvToastDown);
    tvToastDown.setText(message);
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0,0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(v);
    toast.show();

}
```

and the code from 2nd activity:

```
  switch (item.getItemId()){
    case  R.id.btnAddActionBar:

        MainActivity mainActivity= new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.showToastDown(this, "TEXT");
        break;
}
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: post the Logs also

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.LayoutInflater android.view.Window.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object reference`

Comment: check my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from your code, as you are already passing value of context so no need to initialize again with Application Context.

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```

**EDIT**: Change Your Method like this:

```
public void showToastDown(Context context, String message) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_down, (ViewGroup) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.toast_down_root));

    TextView tvToastDown = v.findViewById(R.id.tvToastDown);
    tvToastDown.setText(message);
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL, 0,0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(v);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works, could you explain me what why you downcasted it?

Comment: @Formax your parameter type is Context and getLayoutInflater() is method of Activity, so you can't use it without casting. You can change the parameter type to Activity, then you do not have to cast context to Activity...

Comment: Anytime buddy... Whenever you reach 15 reputation please UpVote the answer... Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems with your code:

1. Never instantiate activities yourself (`mainActivity = new MainActivity`). This doesn't work, only the Android OS can create activities. I suggest taking some (free) beginner android tutorials online to understand how activities work and what their role is.
2. The toast function you've written is a utility function that doesn't appear to have anything to do with `MainActivity`. If you put it as a static function of a different class (whose purpose is only to provide useful utility functions like this) e.g. `ActivityTools.java`, then you can call it from anywhere and pass it a Context like you are doing.
3. In your toast function, you're receiving a context as the first parameter but then immediately overwriting it. This doesn't make any sense, there's no reason to overwrite it like this.